# Remove hidden character and special character (java/javascript)

Tags: javascript, java, encoding, utf-8

I need to remove `[LS]`, [[LS] character only appears when pasted on notepad++ this data was inserted hidden and visible only on UTF-8 encoding editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUKb4.png). And also character such as phone;email;fax.

I used below codes :

```
string.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "").replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}]", "");
```

but also replace the Chinese characters that should not be removed. 
Is there any way to remove hidden character and iconic character without removing the language character?

Comment: Could you add more examples?

Comment: More information please. Was unicode text pasted into Notepad++ and not displayed properly? Where do the highlighted ASCII LS characters in the image come from, how were they produced? Possibly related: [How can I edit Unicode text in Notepad++?](http://superuser.com/questions/21135/how-can-i-edit-unicode-text-in-notepad)

Comment: The information was from email then user copy the whole email and paste to the application and successfully saved. But when retrieving the data we got exception. Until i found out when I copy the data on notepadd++ that has UTF-8 Encoding, there's strange character that is not visible on database / notepad. So I guess there could be other character aside from [LS]

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript or Java? Well, you said

> Remove hidden character and special character (Java / **JavaScript**)

so I suppose JavaScript solution is acceptable too. You can achieve it by a simple regex:

```
string.replace(/[\xa0\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]/g, '');
```

It will remove all invisible characters, but not letters and digits etc.

Comment: @JohnEdwardDelosReyes. How didn't it work? You are trying to do it in JavaScript or Java? Did it throw any errors? Also, what character codes (in unicode) you want to remove exactly?